# whatsie_whatsie.desktop icon not removed

Tags: uninstall, whatsapp

i install whatsie from ubuntu software centere

i removed whatSie but the icon not removed how can i remove it ?

i tried this command

cd /usr/share/applications

[the app folder it's not here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R017Z.png)

sudo snap remove whatsie

still no't removed

[This is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1sYb.png)

Comment: sudo rm /usr/shar/applications/whatsie_whatsie.desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix caching problems with your whatsie icon, try the following:

1. Look under the following folders to find the file you want to remove:

   - `/usr/share/applications` (you already did)
   - `/usr/local/share/applications`
   - `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`
   - `~/.local/share/applications`
   - If you can't find the file, you can always do `find / -iname whatsie` to find leftover files
2. Run `update-desktop-database /path/to/directory` for each of those
3. Rename or delete `~/.cache`
4. Restart your computer